# Powershell Delete Files but keep last x version

Tags: powershell

I have a folder structure with, for example, 100 folders.  Each folder has 200 files in it.

I would like to delete (via scheduled task) all files in each folder but keep the last 10 versions of it.

I am trying to upskill in Powershell so I am guessing that this should be pretty simple.  I have created this script,

```
    #Delete all files, keep last 10 versions#

$Directory = "D:\Octopus\Packages"
$Keep = "10"

Get-ChildItem $Directory| ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv $Directory\FolderList.csv

$FolderList = import-csv $Directory\FolderList.csv

ForEach ($row in $FolderList)
{
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | where{-not $_.PsIsContainer}| sort CreationTime -desc | select -Skip $Keep | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

It appears to be looping through each folder, but keeping the last 10 files for the entire folder structure, not per folder.  So some folders have 0 files, some may have 2 files, some may have 8 files.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean "keep the last 10 versions of it"? of what?

Comment: You're not actually specifying the path in your `get-childitem`. You'll want to modify that to something like `Get-ChildItem $row -recurse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually need to have that CSV then just modify `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` to `Get-ChildItem $row -recurse`. However, if you don't need to be creating the CSV, you can remove of that and just pipe the results of your first `Get-ChildItem` into the next action.

```
$Directory = "D:\Octopus\Packages"
$Keep = "10"

Get-ChildItem $Directory| ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object FullName | 
ForEach-object {Get-ChildItem $_.fullname -Recurse | 
where{-not $_.PsIsContainer}| sort CreationTime -desc | 
select -Skip $Keep | Remove-Item -Force }
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks, that works a treat.  The csv was a combination of trying to get it working, but also stretching my Powershell legs as part of my learning. Wouldn't have been efficient of course.  Thanks for the help !

Comment: Awesome I'm glad I was able to help. If this worked for you, please mark it as the answer. :)